Personal Finance Android app with auto SMS and Gmail transaction tracking
Currently I found two types of personal Finance apps, one is manual entry and the other is SMS parsing with optional manual entry.
The SMS transaction data is vague and there's not much to parse. Also SMS data to be parsed is not semantic unlike email. For example Kobo book, Google Play book, Steam game purchases are shown as unknown in most apps with SMS parsing.
Gmail seems to have sematic formatting and Steam game data is parsed by Gmail to show price, names of products purchased before the email body. So, due to Gmail supporting semantic parsing, most vendors sending email use semantic formatting when sending purchased notices, receipts.
So, I need a personal finance Android app that tracks expenses etc with Gmail parsing in addition to SMS parsing.
For those of you who are skeptical of Gmail parsing being a thing, it is indeed a thing. Google provides API for it. For example there are some some shipping tracking apps that track the tracking IDs of your ordered products from email and shows the data in the App.
